# Static nested resource params name on Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm playing on Rails routing but I can't figure out how to manage this. The problem is at `user_posts(1)` and `user(4)` routes, the params have different names - `id` and `user_id`

What I'm trying to achieve is a static param name for the same resource.

I have this route file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  shallow do
    resources :users, module: :users, only: [:index, :show] do
      resources :posts, module: :posts, only: [:index, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

The routes generated are

```
   user_posts(1) GET  /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)      users/posts/posts#index
   post(2) GET        /posts/:id(.:format)                 users/posts/posts#show
   users(3) GET       /users(.:format)                     users/users#index
   user(4) GET        /users/:id(.:format)                 users/users#show
```

I tried `resources :user param: :user` but the generated route at `user_posts` is `/users/:user_user_id/posts`

Is possible to achieve a `:user_id` param and `:post_id` param for every route using `resources`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
resources :users, param: :user_id
resources :users, only: [] do
    resources :posts, param: :post_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible 'cause it is useless. Your only option is to nest post into the user resources in such manner:

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :posts, only: [:index, :show]
end
```